# import es6 module from npm local dependency without transforming babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a main project written in es6 with this gulpfile:

```
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify');

var sources = ['./src/main.js'];
var destination = '../../public/compiled';

var standalone = 'Round';

gulp.task('dev', function() {
  return browserify('./src/main.js', {
    standalone: standalone
  }).transform('babelify',
               { presets: ["es2015"],
                 plugins: ['add-module-exports'] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('round.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
});
```

and I have this local dependency in package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "game": "file:///home/ubuntu/ui/game",
  },
}
```

`game` module is written in es6. I want my main project to install and import this module in es6 and do the transform itself. But I get this [error](https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/103):

`'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' #103`